# @ symbol in the key in JSON is giving error while accessing it

Tags: javascript, json

I have following JSON element.

```
    "myObj":[
      {
         "@type":"xzy",
         "data" :"pqr"
      }
     ]
```

I am accessing a value inside the array using the key as follows

```
var data = myNode.filter(x => x.@type=='xyz').map(y=>y.data)
```

But I canot do it becuase of the `@` symbol in the key. I tried surrounding it with `'`

```
var data = myNode.filter(x => x.'@type'=='xyz').map(y=>y.data)
```

but again it fails. `@` symbol is valid in JSON. So, I should be able to access it. How can I do this in Javascript? Appreciate your input

Comment: did you tried using `[ ]`,  var data = myNode.filter(x => x['@type'] == 'xyz').map(y=>y.data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var data = myNode.filter(x => x.'@type'=='xyz').map(y=>y.data)
```

Use this:

```
var data = myNode.filter(x => x['@type']=='xyz').map(y=>y.data)
```

**`Square bracket notation`** allows access to properties containing special characters and selection of properties using variables.